# Inno Setup format a number with a thousand separator

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to find a way to format a number with a thousand separator (in this case a comma), so that I can display the number in a more readable and friendly way to the user. I know that clearly I must first convert the integer to a string, using `IntToStr` and then probably use `Length` to return the length of the string and I have been looking at the possibility of using the `Insert` function to insert a comma. The problem is that `Insert` works from the left index position and I am struggling to work out how to do this from the right index. Additionally, I would have to add `1` to the string length for each insert and keep track of how many inserts that have been made. This seems quite a complicated way to do this, especially as the size of the number grows. Is there a simple way to format a number with a thousand separator that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format a number according to the current locale (rather than hard-coding US/UK-style "comma"), use the [`Format` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_format):

```pascal
var
  D: Integer;
  S: string;
begin
  D := 1234567;
  S := Format('%.0n', [double(D)]);
end;
```

The `S` will be:

- UK locale: `1,234,567`
- German locale: `1.234.567`
- Czech locale: `1 234 567`

The `.0` specifies that you want no decimal points (as the input is an integer).

For details, see https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format

Comment: Brilliant! Martin you are a star! That's the simple (and better than hard-coding) solution I was looking for, but couldn't find.